# RabbitMQ - "Not Before" filter

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way to post a message to a rabbit queue in such a way that the message won't be delivered before a given date? Something to fill scenarios like: "This message will trigger protocol X that issue`s warnings to the end-user. The end-user requested not to be disturbed on weekends so this message should not be consumed before Monday 9am"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [delayed exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange) plugin for that. It is intended for these types of use cases.

From the README.

> A user can declare an exchange with the type `x-delayed-message` and then publish messages with the custom header `x-delay` expressing in milliseconds a delay time for the message. The message will be delivered to the respective queues after `x-delay` milliseconds.

You can calculate the desired delay at the publisher.